# Outlook 2007: Is There an Event That Fires If a Rule Is Being Enabled or Disabled

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2007, macros, rules, events

I have written a bunch of macros that allow me to enable or disable a specific Outlook rule (i.e., delayed sending of messages) via a toolbar button. They also change the button's appearance to show me whether the rule is enabled or not. This works fine.

What I needed now would be an event or hook that would be allow me to run the macros when the rule is enabled or disabled in the usual Outlook dialog, so that the button on the toolbar could be synchronized accordingly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying you want the state of the rules (enabled/disabled) in the Manage Rules And Alerts dialog referenced in your custom toolbar?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And my macro's button can already toggle a rule's state and display this state. But I don't know how to update the display when the rule is toggled in the conventional way.

Comment: I can think of 2 hacks, neither ideal. Put a timer on the ribbon control, checking the state of the rules every N seconds. Or, a refresh button in the ribbon control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such event. The only thing you can do is to check the state of your rules periodically. Another way is to write the COM add-in that will advise to IMsgStore's fnevObjectModified.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your answers. I will now deliberate about whether this is worth the trouble.